# ReferenceError: window is not defined when using jsPDF in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, jspdf

I am generating a PDF from HTML using jsPDF in Angular. It is working fine in my local machine, but when I'm creating dist it gives me this error message:

```
(function(t,e){var A,n=1,S=function(t){return t.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\").replace(/\(/g,"\\(").replace(/\)/g,"\\)")},y=function(t){return t.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\").replace(/\\\(/g,"(").replace(/\\\)/g,")")},_=function(t){if(isNaN(t))throw new Error("Invalid argument passed to jsPDF.f2");return t.toFixed(2)},s=function(t){if(isNaN(t))throw new Error("Invalid argument passed to jsPDF.f2");return t.toFixed(5)};t.__acroform__={};var r=function(t,e){t.prototype=Object.create(e.prototype),t.prototype.constructor=t},v=function(t){return t*n},w=function(t){return t/n},l=function(t){var e=new j,n=Y.internal.getHeight(t)||0,r=Y.internal.getWidth(t)||0;return e.BBox=[0,0,Number(_(r)),Number(_(n))],e},i=t.__acroform__.setBit=function(t,e){if(t=t||0,e=e||0,isNaN(t)||isNaN(e))throw new Error("Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.API.__acroform__.setBit");return t|=1<<e},o=t.__acroform__.clearBit=function(t,e){if(t=t||0,e=e||0,isNaN(t)||isNaN(e))throw new Error("Invalid arguments pa

    ReferenceError: window is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:451130:30237)
        at module.exports (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:451091:37)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:451093:112)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:20:30)
        at Object.jspdf (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:432261:18)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
        at Object../src/app/components/users/my-orders/my-orders.component.ts (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:412409:13)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
        at Object../src/app/components/users/my-orders/my-orders.component.ngfactory.js (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:412343:10)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
        at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:380520:11)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
        at Object../src/main.server.ts (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:432090:37)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
        at Object.0 (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:432106:18)
        at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/html/youmakr/dist/server.js:378455:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating dist .Run your project in production mode there might be some error which is restricting your build command.

Comment: ng serve --prod

Comment: No it works file in product mode , without any error , but gives error while build

Comment: Then take clone in another place and run npm install again .
Well i got the same error and it get resolved by doing this.
Hope helps.